# Is there any difference between foo[:product] = "abc" and foo["product"] = "abc" in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Notice, it's not difference between `product = "abc"` and `product = :abc`.

it's `foo[:product] = "abc"` and `foo["product"] = "abc"`, so the question is more about Ruby on rails script parser.
Does RoR also cache/hash class property name?

Answer (score 7):

A normal Ruby Hash will differentiate between the keys `:product` and `"product"`.  An instance of `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` will consider both of those as the same key.

You can call `#with_indifferent_access` on a Hash to convert it, but be aware that you can lose key/value pairs when doing so.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference. Both of these are simply `SyntaxError`s, since neither `:product` nor `"product"` is a legal variable name:

```
"product" = "abc"
# SyntaxError: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting $end
# "product" = "abc"
#            ^

:product = "abc"
# SyntaxError: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting $end
# :product = "abc"
#           ^
```

Comment: I think he was probably referring (albeit incorrectly and non-explicitly) to hashes.

Comment: @coreyward: There is no mention of `Hash`es in the question. There are no `Hash`es in any of the code samples. The question *explicitly* asks about the parser, i.e. about syntax. The *edited* (which, however, was edited without any input from the OP) question now asks about indexing assignments, of which there was no absolutely no indication whatsoever in the original version.